# Is it possible to turn specific locations on and of based on a url

Tags: api, nginx, location, config

I want to enable specific url locations with the use of an API.

My API wil be something like: `https://myurl.com/optional` and will return `true`

Is it possible to turn specific locations on and of based on a url?

```
server {

    root /var/www/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name demo.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
        
        if(https://myurl.com/optional === true){
                location /optional {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:8989;
                }
        }

}
```

I did try to replace the nginx config each time the api will return a different value. But doing this is very fragile.

Comment: A location block doesn't turn that location on or off. It just tells nginx where to find that resource and how to treat it. Are you doing this because the URLs will be user created and you can't predict what they are?

Comment: I have this same configuration with proxy_addresses that I need to turn on and off. Thats why I am interested in turning a specific location on and off based on an API

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your API trying to replace the NGINX configuration every time and provided the number of locations to toggle is limited, you can do it by having a tailored NGINX configuration and having your API create/delete the flag files that would "enable/disable" desired locations.

Note that it wouldn't perform perfectly performance-wise because it [introduces a file check](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-try_files-is-evil-too), but on modern SSDs, this is not very important:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
        
location /optional {
    try_files /optional.disabled @optional_enabled;
}

location = /optional.disabled {
    return 404;
}

location @optional_enabled {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8989;
}
```

To "disable" a location, your API would create `/optional.disabled` file (e.g. by `touch` command).
To "enable" a location, your API would delete the flag file.